# Set theory: Calculating intersection of 3 sets without underlying data

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

**Editing since this seems to be unclear:**  I ONLY have the data listed below.  I do not have any information on the underlying elements.  For example,  I know A&B = 14, but I don't know which 14 elements match, or the values of those 14 elements.

I am trying to determine if the following is possible.

You have 3 sets **A, B, C**

You have the **Size of A**, **Size of B**, and **Size of C**.

You also have the intersect of **A&B**, intersect of **A&C**, and the intersect of **B&C**.

Is it possible to determine the intersect A&B&C?

**Example:**

size A = 25

size B = 30

size C = 22

A&B = 14

A&C = 10

B&C = 9

What is A&B&C?

Also, if this is possible, can it also be done on greater number of sets.  For example, A,B,C,D given you have all intersect pairs?

**Side note:**
I have been able to prove the following, but haven't been able to apply it to >2 sets.

Size A = 10

Size B = 20

AUB = 25

A&B = (size A + size B) - AUB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Consider the following examples:

$A = \{1,2\}$, $B = \{2,3\}$, $C = \{1,3\}$.

$A = \{1,2\}$, $B = \{1,3\}$, $C = \{1,4\}$.

In each, $|A| = |B| = |C| = 2$ and $|A\cap B| = |B\cap C| = |A\cap C| = 1$. 
But in the first example, $|A\cap B\cap C| = 0$, while in the second example, $|A\cap B\cap C| = 1$.